# How to choose between multiple network connections through command line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have two network connections - wifi and ethernet. How to choose a specific network to use while using command line eg. `ping google.com`.

PS: I mentioned ping as an example. I may be running a python script or curl and it should use same interface for all these.

Comment: I've voted to move this to SuperUser as it's not about programming within the scope defined in the SO help centre - i.e. at all, really.

Comment: Of course, you might prefer the Unix/Linux sister site instead.

Comment: Yeah. I am waiting to post on Superuser. It will allow me to post only after 40 min.

Comment: You can set a default gateway with `ip` command. Can you modify the `python` code?

Answer (score 4):

you can use the -I flag

```
-I interface address
   Set source address to specified interface address. Argument may be numeric IP address or name of device.
```

example

```
ping -I eth0 8.8.8.8
ping -I wlan0 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: I used ping as an example. Sorry. What if I am running a python script.

Comment: @Bytemare Then that's a separate question